# How to open a application in mac with maxmized screen

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open a application and ensure its maximized to use mouse coordinates. How to do that.

Tried openai but nothing seems to help for adobe bridge maximizing is elusive. Please help.

Command line doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58875/open-an-app-in-fullscreen-via-terminal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.